# How to fix 'Swift Protocols/Delegates setting UIImages - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value'?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, delegates, uiimage, protocols

I am letting the user choose a background image upon sign in. Base on user choice of image selection, I want to show another view controller with the image that the user selected. I follow some examples from youtube but I am getting 'Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value' and the image is not set.

```
protocol SelectionImageDelegate {

    func setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage)
}


class SelectBackgroundViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var snowBackgroundImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var desertBackgroundImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pathwayBackgroundImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var beachBackgroundImage: UIImageView!

    // MARK: Properties
    var imageSelectionDelegate: SelectionImageDelegate!


    // MARK: Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageSelectionDelegate = FootprintViewController()
        setButtonCorners()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        snowBackgroundImage.center.x  -= view.bounds.width
        desertBackgroundImage.center.x -= view.bounds.width
        pathwayBackgroundImage.center.x -= view.bounds.width
        beachBackgroundImage.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    }


    @IBAction func didTappedSnowBackground(_ sender: Any) {
        print("tapped snow")
        imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Snow_Background")!)
        print("set image")
        let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FootprintVC"))!
        self.presentViewController(vc)
    }


    @IBAction func didTappedDesertBackground(_ sender: Any) {
        imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Desert_Background")!)
        let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FootprintVC"))!
        self.presentViewController(vc)
    }


    @IBAction func didTappedPathwayBackground(_ sender: Any) {
        imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Pathway_Background")!)
        let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FootprintVC"))!
        self.presentViewController(vc)
    }


    @IBAction func didTappedBeachBackground(_ sender: Any) {
        imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Beach_Background")!)
        let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FootprintVC"))!
        self.presentViewController(vc)
    }

}


class FootprintViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emptyFootprintImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: Life Cycles
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

extension FootprintViewController: SelectionImageDelegate {

    func setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage) {
        backgroundImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
}

class FootprintViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emptyFootprintImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: Life Cycles
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

extension FootprintViewController: SelectionImageDelegate {

    func setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage) {
        backgroundImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: The exception is found at         imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage(named: "Snow_Background")!, color: .red)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set optinal imageSelectionDelegate in SelectBackgroundViewController like this;

`var imageSelectionDelegate: SelectionImageDelegate?`

Comment: The error goes away by setting it as optional but the image is not set because it is nil. :(

Answer (score 0):

"implicitly unwrapping" means that you are trying to access an "implicitly unwrapped optional" value, which does not hold a value but is `nil`.

In your case, you are dealing with two optionals:

- The delegate `imageSelectionDelegate` might not be set.
- `UIImage(named: "Snow_Background")` might return `nil`

Accessing the delegate - if `nil` would result in the `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` error, while accessing the image - if `nil` - would result in `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

So, since you observe the first error, the delegate is nil, which seems strange because you set it in `viewDidLoad`.

To investigate a little more, you could add some more trace information to your action handler, to check what happens:

```
@IBAction func didTappedSnowBackground(_ sender: Any) {
    print("tapped snow")

    guard imageSelectionDelegate != nil else {
        print ("delegate is not set")
        return
    }

    guard let bgImage = UIImage(named: "Snow_Background") else {
        print ("Snow_Background image does not exist")
        return
    }

    imageSelectionDelegate.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: bgImage)
    print("set image")
    let vc = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FootprintVC"))!
    self.presentViewController(vc)
}
```

Then check the output.

Comment: I am getting "delegate is not set".

Comment: Please set a breakpoint at the print statement ("delegate not set") and show is the callstack. Also set a breakpoint at `viewDidLoad`. This should be reached before the print breakpoint

Comment: if I remove 'weak' from imageSelectionDelegate, the selected image was being passed to the FootprintVC. However, I am still getting a nil error. Please see below. Your help is greatly appreciated.
extension FootprintViewController: SelectionImageDelegate {
    func setBackgroundImage(selectedImage: UIImage, color: UIColor) {
        backgroundImageView.image = selectedImage // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value is found here
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }
}